# Missing Unicode support on Windows FrontEnd

Tags: front-end, fonts, unicode

Does *Mathematica* FrontEnd still not support all the Unicode characters in version 12? I am using version 12 on Windows 10 and can't get character ↳ (U+21b3). It fails to print using `\:21b3` in the FrontEnd. Even Notepad now supports this. Can someone check whether this is the issue with Windows FrontEnd  only or with other platforms as well?

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)

Comment: It seems to work for me, so it may be OS specific. Version: 12.0.0 for Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019).

Comment: I think the front-end capabilities of Mathematica for Windows is way behind that of Mac. There is no high DPI support on Windows. On my high resolution screen, the font of Mathematica looks blurry. They claim to have this fixed in 12.1 so hopefully they will update the unicode support as well. I will bring this issue up in the SW livestream.

Comment: @user13892 the default font on Windows (i.e. Consolas) does not support that character.  You can see for yourself in Character Map.

Comment: @ihojnicki But which font supports this character? Notepad by default uses "Lucida Console" which also doesn't have this character according to Character Map, but it does display it correctly. MS Word also displays this character correctly but says that the font is "MS Mincho" which isn't installed on my system. How Windows displays this character at all?

Comment: It is a matter of font fallback algorithms. And Windows has two of them (maybe more, I haven't checked super recently) . I plan on switching it, but it will not happen this year.